# Draw circle with 6 points on it

Tags: android

[image: target result]

How to draw canvas like on image? There are no problems with the circle, but how to symmetrically arrange the points?

What now i have:

[image: current result]

```
    private val backgroundPaint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.LTGRAY
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeWidth = backgroundWidth
        isAntiAlias = true
    }

    private val oval = RectF()
    private var centerX: Float = 0f
    private var centerY: Float = 0f
    private var radius: Float = 0f

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        centerX = w.toFloat() / 2
        centerY = h.toFloat() / 2
        radius = w.toFloat() / 2 - progressWidth
        oval.set(centerX - radius,
            centerY - radius,
            centerX + radius,
            centerY + radius)
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas?.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, backgroundPaint)
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add some code of what you've tried till now? to give us a starting point.

Comment: Okey, code added.

Answer (score 1):

your 6 small circles above are at 0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300 degrees around the circle. You can draw a circle in a single command (canvas.drawCircle), so your problem is now to figure out where to draw those circles.

If the centre of a circle is at {0,0}, with a radius of r, you can derive the {X, Y} of a point on the circumference at angle t, by using:

```
X = cos(t)*r
Y = sin(t)*r
```

Comment: My cos(60.0)  and sin (60.0) has negative values so X/Y has wrong. Hmm.

Comment: The results will be offsets from a (0,0) origin. You need to add the coordinates of the centre of your circle to them. Like I said above, "If the centre of a circle is at {0,0}...".

Comment: Hi @Hombre, any luck?

Comment: Nope. I did it another way. https://paste.ee/p/vFOtt

Comment: Well done, although that is the method I described, isn't it? I'm not familiar with the language you are using.